# I can't send a picture attachment within a text message - using NET10 (Motorola ATRIX 2)

Tags: sms, photos, attachments

I can't send a picture attachment within a text message - using NET10 (Motorola ATRIX 2) - have only had the service for a month and this is the first time I've tried sending a picture

Comment: Why can't you? What have you tried? What were you missing / were did you get stuck? Is an APN for MMS set up on your device? SMS themselves cannot handle pictures -- they are text-only and limited to 160 chars.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Net10 is famous for this issue - happened to me too. I ended up using a free third party messaging app (Handcent works for me) and I can send and receive picture messages now with no problems. Download one of these messaging apps, and you will not really tell that it is not the messaging app that came with the phone originally; they work and integrate that well.

Answer (score -1):

I also recommend a third party app, but I'd recommend hello bc in addition to sending photos, it handles group text messages the best, another big issue with android text messaging in my opinion.